# Box2D Actionscript 3 question

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder, box2d

I've created a world using box2d in action script 3 and i've got a small box to move on keyboard left, right up etc but when the user for example keeps pressing the up button even in the air, the small box keeps going higher.

How would i only allow the user to go higher in the air only after it has touched some over shape

```
    C.log("UP Key pressed");
    myChar.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(0, -1) );
    myChar.ApplyForce(new b2Vec2(0, -100), myChar.GetPosition());
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, you may be interest in this: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=135.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of whether or not the object is grounded. Put SetLinearVelocity inside an if statement that checks that variable, and set the variable to false in the if statement:

```
var grounded:Boolean = true;
...
if (grounded) {
  SetLinearVelocity
  grounded = false;
}
```

Then on collisions with the ground set the variable back to true.

Comment: Yes but how do i check if its grounded?

Comment: Make a collider object for the ground and then set "grounded = true" when the box collides with the ground.

Answer (score 3):

Collision detection in box2d flash was one of the hardest things for me to get my head around when I first started out.
Information on all collisions is provided by the contact listener class. To react to specific collisions (for example, the collision between myChar and your ground objects), you need to override functions in the base contact listener class, and check that the contact is one that you're interested in. Specifically override the BeginContact and EndContact functions and check that the contact is between the player body and a ground body. These functions are fired when two bodies first contact and stop contacting respectively, and the b2Contact class they accept as a parameter has information on which two fixtures are colliding.

So, in your overrided BeginContact function you'd check to see if either body is a ground body and the other is the player, and then set your grounded variable to true. In your overrided EndContact function, you'd again check to make sure the contact is referring to the right bodies, and then set your grounded variable to false. Finally, when the player presses the jump key, check the grounded variable and if true, allow the player to jump.

Some semi-psuedo code:

```
override BeginContact(contact:b2Contact):void {
    check to see whether GetFixtureA().GetBody() or GetFixtureB().GetBody() is ground and the other is player
        grounded = true;
}

override EndContact(contact:b2Contact):void {
    again, check both bodies
        grounded = false;
}
```

Depending on how you've set out your ground bodies, it might be a better idea to keep a count of how many ground bodies the player is currently contacting, and if this count is greater than 0, allow the player to jump.

[Todd's Box2D Tutorials](http://www.kerp.net/box2d/) were the most useful resource for me. Although they refer to box2d 2.02 rather than the latest 2.10, the [contact listener stuff](http://www.kerp.net/box2d/displaylesson.php?chapter=2&lesson=15) is similar. The code comments in the box2d source files also have useful implementation guidelines.

I hope this gets you started. Let me know if anything could be clearer.